# How to change user agent sent by firefox?

Tags: firefox-for-android

I'd like to change user agent in firefox runnig on android, but there is no add-on for this, and no about:config.
What can I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could install an older version of firefox from before the removal of "about:config".  I've gone for "firefox nightly", which also has it.

Answer (score -1):

The User-Agent Switcher [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-string-switcher/) says that it supports Android. Second link on a web search.

Comment: I visited that link with Firefox for Android. I don't see anywhere where it says "it supports Firefox for Android".